# How to get Ajax posted Array in my C# controller?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, arrays

I work with ASP.NET-MVC. I try to post an array in ajax but I don't know how to get it in my controller. Here is my code :

Ajax

```
var lines = new Array();
lines.push("ABC");
lines.push("DEF");
lines.push("GHI");
$.ajax(
{
    url: 'MyController/MyAction/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 'lines': lines },
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

MyController

```
public JsonResult MyAction(string[] lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(lines); // Display nothing
    return Json(new { data = 0 });
}
```

Why I can't see my lines ? How to properly post this array and use it in MyAction ?

Comment: Try with `traditional: true` ajax settings parameter.

Comment: Try `{ 'lines' : JSON.stringify(lines)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the `contentType: "application/json"` option and `JSON.stringify` your parameter:

```
var lines = new Array();
lines.push("ABC");
lines.push("DEF");
lines.push("GHI");
$.ajax(
{
    url: 'MyController/MyAction/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'lines': lines }),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

You can also set the type of objects you're getting if it makes sense in your business case.  Example:

```
public JsonResult MyAction(string[] lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(lines); // Display nothing
    return Json(new { data = 0 });
}
```

And, something more practical with what you're sending in:

```
public class MyModel {
    string[] lines;
}
```

and finally:

```
public JsonResult MyAction(MyModel request)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", request.lines)); // Display nothing
    return Json(new { data = 0 });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First, try to change:

```
data: { 'lines': lines }
```

to

```
data: { lines: lines },
```

If it won't help, try to use json.stringify(lines)