# AngularJS object is not properly converted into a ViewModel .NET

Tags: c#, angularjs

I have an AngularJS directive which returns me an array with some values, like this below:

[image]

The AngularJS code I'm using to generate this object like above is:

```
//--------------------------
// service...

service.getSelectedOptions = function() {
    var options = [];
    for (var I = 0; I < service.optionList.length; ++I) {
        var availableOption = service.optionList[I];

        if (availableOption.selecionado !== '') {
            options.push(availableOption);
        }
    }
    return opcoes;
};

//--------------------------
// controller...
var options = [];
var list = OptionsService.getSelectedOptions();
for (var I = 0; I < list.length; ++I) {
    var option = list[I];
    options.push({ Handle: option.Handle, Selecionado: option.Selecionado });
}
console.log(options);

// Sending the values to backend...
doPost('..../SaveOptions', { options: options }, function (result) {  });
```

Ok, I created a ViewModel class to receive those objects into my controller.

```
public class OptionsViewModel {
    public int Handle { get; set; }
    public string Selecionado { get; set; }
}
```

My controller is declared like this below:

```
public JsonResult SaveOptions(OptionsViewModel[] options) {
    //...
}
```

The problem is: if I chose 4 options, the array in the backend has 4 options, but the values are not binded to the objects.

[image]

Why that? Anyone knows why? Thanks!!

Comment: Can you post the method for `OptionsService.getSelectedOptions();`

Comment: @tymeJV The code is added.

Comment: Is anything in that service a data call to the backend?

Comment: If you look at the network tab of your browser, what is the actual POST being sent to the controller?

Comment: @JaimeTorres the SaveOptions POST method is sent to the controller. The POST is executing properly, the problem is to bind the JS object values to the ViewModel array as parameter from my controller method.

Comment: @tymeJV No, it just gets some data I added into the `$scope` from my controller's screen.

Comment: @Kiwanax right, but sometimes it's easy to see what the issue is if you interrogate the post.  This is normally easier than customizing the model-binder to see what's coming in.

Comment: @JaimeTorres got it. The first screenshot is about the object was generated by the Javascript. I'm not understanding WHY it's not being binded properly to the viewmodel.

Comment: But, can you post what the POST is?  Are you using the $http service?  If you are using MVC (not WebAPI), it needs contentType to be explicitly 'application/json' with a 'json' dataType

Comment: @JaimeTorres I'm using jQuery AJAX. "doPost" is a function similar to $.post from jQuery lib. The problem isn't in the lib. Other kind of data is send successfully, except these options array.

Comment: I understand.  I've just seen this problem several times before:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768484/how-to-get-ajax-posted-array-in-my-c-sharp-controller/19768563#19768563  Interrogating the actual POST will tell you if you are sending the appropriate headers or not for MVC.

Comment: @JaimeTorres Yeah! Setting the `contentType` the list is properly bound. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The solution was modify two parameters in the AJAX call:

1. Set `contentType: "application/json"`;
2. Use `JSON.stringify(parameters)` to the parameters.

Thanks!