# Receving null value in controller action via AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Salaamun Alekum

I am getting `null` in controller action via an AJAX request:

```js
var ProjectPermission = [{ 
    "CreatedBy": "Akshay" 
},{ 
    "CreatedBy": "Kumar" 
},{ 
    "CreatedBy": "ETC" 
}]

$.ajax({
    url: '/api/Projects/AssignProjectPermissions', 
    type: 'POST', 
    contentType: 'application/json', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    data: JSON.stringify({ 
        ProjectPermission: ProjectPermission 
    }), 
    success: function (data) { 
        alert(data); 
    },
    // processData: false //Doesn't help
});
```

My C# controller:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost, System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public string AssignProjectPermissions(ProjectPermission[] ProjectPermission)
{
```

I am getting `null` in `ProjectPermission`. I already tried other answers but none of them worked for me. These were the posts I checked:

- [How to get Ajax posted Array in my C# controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768484/how-to-get-ajax-posted-array-in-my-c-sharp-controller)
- [Ajax post to ASP.net MVC controller - object properties are null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547491/ajax-post-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-object-properties-are-null)

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried data: JSON.stringify(ProjectPermission)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be using GET and POST on the same method first of all, just use POST in this case. That aside you do not need the property name. You are putting your array inside of an object. Your method is expecting an array.

```
var ProjectPermission = [{ CreatedBy: "Akshay" },
               { CreatedBy: "Kumar" },
               { CreatedBy: "ETC" }]
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/Projects/AssignProjectPermissions'
    , type: 'POST'
    , contentType: 'application/json'
    , dataType: 'json'
    , data: JSON.stringify(ProjectPermission) //<------------issue here
    , success: function (data) 
         { alert(data); }
        //, processData: false 
    });
```